# Appscript - modify google sheets access permissions Edit to viewer

Tags: google-sheets

Hi everybody good morning!

I've tried to create code that would allow me to change people's access permissions to no avail. Basically you want to change users with editor permissions to only comments or viewers. I hope someone can help me

This is the code

```
function cambiarPermisos() {
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var users = file.getEditors();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    var email = user.getEmail();
    var newRole = DriveApp.AclRole.EDITOR;
    var fileAcl = file.getAccessControlList();
    var existingRule = fileAcl.getEffectivePermission(user).getRole();
    if (existingRule != newRole) {
      if (newRole == DriveApp.AclRole.VIEWER) {
        file.addViewer(email);
        file.removeEditor(email);
      } else {
        file.addEditor(email);
        file.removeViewer(email);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this is the error

10:47:56    Error
TypeError: file.getEditors is not a function
cambiarPermisos @ Código.gs:3

I'd think it's a bug because my domain has restricted certain features for script editing, but I want to make sure it's not a bug in the code.

change people's access permissions in google sheets

Answer (score 1):

The code errors out because `file` points to a `Sheet` object. The `addViewer()`, `addEditor()`, `removeViewer()` and `removeEditor()` methods are only available with `Spreadsheet` objects.

There are other issues with the code as well. For example:

```
    var newRole = DriveApp.AclRole.EDITOR;
    // ...
    if (newRole == DriveApp.AclRole.VIEWER) {
```

The `if` condition will always be false, because the value in `newRole` will never be equal to `DriveApp.AclRole.VIEWER`.

See [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Comment: Thanksss!!! I found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution

```
    function changePermissions() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var editors = ss.getEditors();
  for (var i = 0; i < editors.length; i++) {
    ss.removeEditor(editors[i]);
    ss.addViewer(editors[i]);
  }
}
```